# Word for "Thriving in Chaos"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Looking for a noun describing people who *thrive in chaos*. This is different from people who *like* chaos.

*Antifragile* was proposed by Taleb at some point, but not sure if it suggests the same.

Comment: Our existing question which quotes Taleb defines antifragility as "a system or process that benefits from volatility, stress, or uncertainty". That would certainly appear to fit "thrive in chaos". So this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: 'Vibranium', 'self-annealing', 'self-tempered', 'ever-annealing'